# Eliminar uma chave de todos os arrays caso esteja nula ou em branco

Tags: php, array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Foto] => imagem.jpg
            [Código] => 311102
            [Tipo] => Meu tipo
            [Cidade] => Araçatuba
            [Valor] => 
            [Mais Info] => Todos juntos
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Foto] => imagem2.jpg
            [Código] => 3111022
            [Tipo] => Meu tipo2
            [Cidade] => Araçatuba2
            [Valor] => 
            [Mais Info] => Todos juntos2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Foto] => imagem3.jpg
            [Código] => 3111023
            [Tipo] => Meu tipo3
            [Cidade] =>
            [Valor] => 
            [Mais Info] => Todos juntos3
        )
)
```

**Gostaria que a saída fosse assim, elimiando o campo valor pq em todos os subarray esta em branco ou nulo**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Foto] => imagem.jpg
            [Código] => 311102
            [Tipo] => Meu tipo
            [Cidade] => Araçatuba
            [Mais Info] => Todos juntos
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Foto] => imagem2.jpg
            [Código] => 3111022
            [Tipo] => Meu tipo2
            [Cidade] => Araçatuba2
            [Mais Info] => Todos juntos2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Foto] => imagem3.jpg
            [Código] => 3111023
            [Tipo] => Meu tipo3
            [Cidade] =>
            [Mais Info] => Todos juntos3
        )
)
```

alguém já passou por isso?
marco

Answer (score 0):

Galera abei tentando aqui e consegui

supomos que o $arr_comp é o meu array acima citado.

```
        foreach($arr_comp as $cha => $val){
            foreach($val as $cha2 => $val2){
                $arr_new[$cha2][] = $val2;          
            }   
        }

        unset($arr_comp);
        foreach($arr_new as $cha => $val){
            if (count(array_filter($val)) > 0){
                foreach($val as $cha2 => $val2){
                    $arr_comp[$cha2][$cha] = ($val2 == '' ? '-' : $val2);           
                }
            }
        }
```

Valeu..